# Deserialize JSON from restful call

Tags: json, swift, web-services, rest

I'm trying to consume the data (JSON) returned from my restful call. The following is data returned from my call (array of key/value pairs, always 4 key/value pairs for each item in the list):

```
[{"Key":"DATALOG_MAX_ID","Val":"875250","DataType":1,"Description”:”N/A.”},{“Key":"SNAPSHOT_DATALOG_ID","Val":"875259","DataType":1,"Description”:”N/A“},{“Key":"SNAPSHOT_FILE_SIZE","Val":"492590686","DataType":1,"Description”:”N/A“},{“Key":"SNAPSHOT_GEN_ID","Val":"770","DataType":1,"Description”:”N/A”},{“Key":"SNAPSHOT_LAST_UPDATED","Val":"2017-04-14 00:01:17.240","DataType":6,"Description”:”N/A“},{“Key":"SNAPSHOT_MAX_ID","Val":"374418","DataType":1,"Description”:”N/A”},{“Key":"SNAPSHOT_READY","Val":"0","DataType":4,"Description”:”N/A”},{“Key":"SNAPSHOT_REQUIRES_BUILD","Val":"1","DataType":4,"Description”:”N/A”}]
```

If I deserialize this using the following line of code:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as![Dictionary<String, Any>]
```

It succeeds but values are only present in 2 out of the 4 key/value pairs for each dictionary in the array. If you step through and inspect the variables, I notice the Builtin.rawpointer is always 0x0 for the values that are missing.

Oddly, if I try to deserialize using the following line:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as![MetaDataEntry]
```

Strangely, it succeeds and I can see all the data is there (see below screen shot).

[image]

Comment: Many of the strings are enclosed in typographical quotes (e.g. `”N/A.”`). That would be a problem – or did you not copy the JSON correctly?

Comment: I had to modify the data a little because of the organization I work for but its correct (e.g. no issues with the quotes)

Comment: Copy/paste that JSON into https://jsonlint.com and you'll see that there *are* issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me but I had to fix some of the quotes

```
let jsonString = "[{\"Key\":\"DATALOG_MAX_ID\",\"Val\":\"875250\",\"DataType\":1,\"Description\":\"N/A.\"},{\"Key\":\"SNAPSHOT_DATALOG_ID\",\"Val\":\"875259\",\"DataType\":1,\"Description\":\"N/A\"},{\"Key\":\"SNAPSHOT_FILE_SIZE\",\"Val\":\"492590686\",\"DataType\":1,\"Description\":\"N/A\"},{\"Key\":\"SNAPSHOT_GEN_ID\",\"Val\":\"770\",\"DataType\":1,\"Description\":\"N/A\"},{\"Key\":\"SNAPSHOT_LAST_UPDATED\",\"Val\":\"2017-04-14 00:01:17.240\",\"DataType\":6,\"Description\":\"N/A\"},{\"Key\":\"SNAPSHOT_MAX_ID\",\"Val\":\"374418\",\"DataType\":1,\"Description\":\"N/A\"},{\"Key\":\"SNAPSHOT_READY\",\"Val\":\"0\",\"DataType\":4,\"Description\":\"N/A\"},{\"Key\":\"SNAPSHOT_REQUIRES_BUILD\",\"Val\":\"1\",\"DataType\":4,\"Description\":\"N/A\"}]"

let data = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as?[[String:AnyObject]] {

    for row in json {
        print(row)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
["Val": 875250, "Key": DATALOG_MAX_ID, "DataType": 1, "Description": N/A.]
["Val": 875259, "Key": SNAPSHOT_DATALOG_ID, "DataType": 1, "Description": N/A]
["Val": 492590686, "Key": SNAPSHOT_FILE_SIZE, "DataType": 1, "Description": N/A]
["Val": 770, "Key": SNAPSHOT_GEN_ID, "DataType": 1, "Description": N/A]
["Val": 2017-04-14 00:01:17.240, "Key": SNAPSHOT_LAST_UPDATED, "DataType": 6, "Description": N/A]
["Val": 374418, "Key": SNAPSHOT_MAX_ID, "DataType": 1, "Description": N/A]
["Val": 0, "Key": SNAPSHOT_READY, "DataType": 4, "Description": N/A]
["Val": 1, "Key": SNAPSHOT_REQUIRES_BUILD, "DataType": 4, "Description": N/A]
```

Comment: @Paul: So what was the problem?

Comment: I think it was the double quotes used and the casting was wrong

Comment: @Scriptable: But OP claimed in a comment that there are no issues with the quotes. Once the quotes are fixed, OP's code would work as well.  And if the casting were wrong, why should there be *"... only 2 out of the 4 key/value pairs"*? – I am asking (and insisting) because this Q&A is useless for future readers if the problem statement is unclear.

Comment: There was definitely issues with the quotes when copied from the question above. may see the difference here `"Description”:”N/A.”}`

Comment: @Scriptable: Yes, but that means that OP did not show the correct JSON. With those wrong quotes there would be no result at all, and not *"... 2 out of the 4 key/value pairs for each dictionary"*

Comment: I'm not sure then @MartinR, I was just trying to help clarify. I changed the quotes and the casting and it worked. So must be the casting used

Comment: The problem was casting. I was casting the data to [Dictionary<String, Any>] when it should have been [[String:AnyObject]]. As far as the issue with the quotes, that was my fault when copying since I had to modify it slightly because of sensitive information.